# ubuntu 10.04; kvm bridged networking not working with public ip addresses

Tags: networking, ubuntu, kvm-virtualization, bridge

I have a dedicated hosted server box with ubuntu 10.04 64 bit installed.  I would like to run kvm with ubuntu 8.04 installed for some php 5.2 compatible apps(they don't work right with php 5.3, the default in ubuntu 10.04).

I installed KVM as instructed at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/KVM/Installation .  I installed the vm using virt-manager.  I never could figure out how use virt-install or any of those automated installers.  I just installed it using the disc.  I set up bridged networking as per https://help.ubuntu.com/community/KVM/Networking . However, the bridged connection doesn't work.

Here's my /etc/network/interfaces on the host, running ubuntu 10.04.    (with specific public ip blanked)

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet manual

auto br0
iface br0 inet static
        address xx.xx.xx.xx
        netmask 255.255.255.248
        gateway xx.xx.xx.xa
        bridge_ports eth0
        bridge_stp on
        bridge_fd 0
        bridge_maxwait 10
`
```

Here's my /etc/network/interfaces on the guest, running ubuntu 8.04.

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address xx.xx.xx.xy
netmask 255.255.255.248
gateway xx.xx.xx.xa
```

The two vm's can communicate to each other.  But, the guest vm can't access anyone in the real world.

Here's my /etc/libvirt/qemu/store_804.xml

```
<domain type='kvm'>
  <name>store_804</name>
  <uuid>27acfb75-4f90-a34c-9a0b-70a6927ae84c</uuid>
  <memory>2097152</memory>
  <currentMemory>2097152</currentMemory>
  <vcpu>2</vcpu>
  <os>
            <type arch='x86_64' machine='pc-0.12'>hvm</type>
            <boot dev='hd'/>
              </os>
  <features>
    <acpi/>
    <apic/>
    <pae/>
  </features>
  <clock offset='utc'/>
  <on_poweroff>destroy</on_poweroff>
  <on_reboot>restart</on_reboot>
      <on_crash>restart</on_crash>
      <devices>
            <emulator>/usr/bin/kvm</emulator>
    <disk type='file' device='disk'>
      <driver name='qemu' type='raw'/>
      <source file='/var/lib/libvirt/images/store_804.img'/>
      <target dev='hda' bus='ide'/>
    </disk>
    <disk type='block' device='cdrom'>
      <driver name='qemu' type='raw'/>
      <target dev='hdc' bus='ide'/>
      <readonly/>
            </disk>
                    <interface type='bridge'>
      <mac address='52:54:00:26:0b:c6'/>
      <source bridge='br0'/>
      <model type='virtio'/>
        </interface>
    <console type='pty'>
      <target port='0'/>
    </console>
    <console type='pty'>
      <target port='0'/>
    </console>
    <input type='mouse' bus='ps2'/>
    <graphics type='vnc' port='-1' autoport='yes'/>
            <sound model='es1370'/>
    <video>
      <model type='cirrus' vram='9216' heads='1'/>
    </video>
  </devices>
</domain>
```

Any idea where I've gone wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You can't use bridge mode in such environment, you can almost be certain that the hosting partner will block all traffic not originating from the MAC-address of the real NIC in your server. You'll need to setup a routed setup, in which all traffic to/from VM guests are send through your host. One way of doing this is using the native Libvirt support of routed networking ("forward mode="route" in the XML-configuration of the network).

There's a German server hosting company who has written a couple of guides on the subject, you can use Google translate to translate it into English, in case you don't understand German :)
http://wiki.hetzner.de/index.php/Kategorie:KVM

Comment: Thanks.  That makes perfect sense.  I shall try it and report back if all works well.

Comment: Thats odd Kenni, I'm doing exactly this in my data center at the moment. Works fine.

Comment: Depends on the data center; mine don't allow it either.  It's a reasonable decision for them to take and they do provide instructions to work around it, but can't get the damn thing to work anyway... http://wiki.hetzner.de/index.php/KVM_mit_Nutzung_aller_IPs_-_the_easy_way

Answer (score 0):

The guest also needs a default route. Do you have that?

So, you're doing all this just to get a new (downgraded) version of an app? Why not just build (or find, or install from source) a PHP 6.2 package in the host?

Comment: I had already checked that.  

    Kernel IP routing table
    Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
    xx.xx.xx.8     *               255.255.255.248 U     0      0        0 eth0
    default         xx.xx.xx.9     0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 eth0

That is the automatically generated routes table, which looks good to me.

Comment: As far as building PHP 5.2 from source, or downgrading manually;  I have followed some procedures install PHP 5.2 manually.  However, there are many more things needed like mysqli and phpmyadmin, all of which I couldn't easily figure out how to downgrade.  Instead of chasing a bunch of dependencies, I would rather just install the store software on a supported platform.

Comment: Ah well, just switch to Gentoo. ;-)